# What is the function of should in this sentence?

Tags: should

“It’s up to employees to make the case, post-virus, that their employers **should** invest in additional training and skills"

I thought but couldn't find an exact function.

Comment: Its syntactic function is **predicator** in the clause "should invest ..."

Comment: Do you mean to ask if it Is a verb?